# Install Tensorflow on Oracle Application Server with AIX

Tags: python, oracle, aix, oracle-application-server

I would like to install python and Tensorflow on the Oracle Application Server operating on IBM AIX. I have not been able to find any documentation for installing python on AIX, much less on Oracle Application Server. Is this configuration technically possible/supported/documented?

Answer (score 0):

There are no Windows binaries for AIX.  Therefore I needed to compile from source using information found here: [Install Tensorflow from Source.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)